# Polygon editor to draw collision data over image

Tags: xna, collision-detection

I need an editor to plot a polygon over the texture for of a ship  in my game.

It would look like this..
Where the red is the collision outline and the image is the texture.
[image]

I want to store the polygon like texture coordinates eg top left is (0, 0) and bottom right is (1, 1).

Are there any tools (free) that does something similar to this, I'll be working with xna and C#.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but, can't you draw a polygon on top of an entity image with MS Paint?

Comment: @pek, He's looking to have the red lines stored as meta-data so that he can use them to detect collisions more accurately. He doesn't actually want a red line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OS X, you can use [PhysicsEditor](http://www.physicseditor.de/). It is a tool for Box2D or Chimpmunk but there is a txt export for your need. The main difficulty is to find a mac.

Note: there is a windows version too. But i didn't use it. Try it and add a comment if it is useful.

Comment: Yeah, it needs to run on windows

Comment: Physics editor is available for windows now. http://www.physicseditor.de/

Answer (score 3):

[InkScape](http://inkscape.org/) is a good choice for vectorial images.

- Size your document to 1m x 1m...
- Add the bitmap...
- Draw the polyline...
- Save as .svg or .xaml document... whose are text based...
- Develop a light parser to load the data

Comment: +1 [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) also provides a simple vector-based drawing tool that can also be exported to [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), and I think this an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

While a tool like PhysicsEditor (see Ellis answer) is certainly better, the poor mans choice would be to use an [HTML-image-map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map) editor. The coordinates for image-maps are in pixels, but you could simply divide these by *image-height* or *image-width* respectively to get coordinates in the 0..1 range.

Here's an [online-tool](http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap) to draw such image-maps, and [here's another one](http://toolserver.org/~dapete/ImageMapEdit/ImageMapEdit.html).